# How to find count of objects with the highest count?

Tags: mysql

```
create table foos (id, val1, ...)

create table bars (id, foo_id, val2. ...)
```

---

```
insert into foos (1, 1, ..)

insert into foos (2, 2, ..)

insert into foos (3, 3, ..)
```

---

```
insert into bars (1, 1, 1, ..)

insert into bars (2, 1, 1, ..)

insert into bars (3, 1, 1, ..)

insert into bars (4, 2, 1, ..)

insert into bars (5, 2, 1, ..)

insert into bars (6, 2, 1, ..)

insert into bars (7, 2, 1, ..)

insert into bars (8, 3, 1, ..)
```

I would want to count bars like this, how should I do it in a decreasing count order

```
2, 4 (foo 2 has 4 bars)

1, 3 (foo 1 has 3 bars)

3, 1 (foo 3 has a bar)
```

Comment: Please explain what you did to get this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `foo_id`, COUNT(1) AS `count`
FROM `bars`
GROUP BY `foo_id`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

Here's the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b91d3/1) link.